# finding the captial letters in the string

Tags: r, plyr, stringr

I want find the captial letters in the each string and counting how many are there for each string 
for example

```
t = c("gctaggggggatggttactactGtgctatggactac", "gGaagggacggttactaCgTtatggactacT", "gcGaggggattggcttacG")  

ldply(str_match_all(t,"[A-Z]"),length)
```

when applying the above function my output is

```
1 4 2
```

But my desire output is

> [1] G -1
>
> [2] G -1
>          C -1
>          T -2
>
> [3] G -2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you extend docendo's answer to be your exact requested format

```
lapply(stringr::str_extract_all(t, "[A-Z]"), 
       function(x) {
         x = table(x)
         paste(names(x), x, sep = "-")
       })

# [[1]]
# [1] "G-1"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "C-1" "G-1" "T-2"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "G-2"
```

and how i would do it in tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)
data = data.frame(strings = c("gctaggggggatggttactactGtgctatggactac", "gGaagggacggttactaCgTtatggactacT", "gcGaggggattggcttacG"))
data  %>%
  mutate(caps_freq = stringr::str_extract_all(strings, "[A-Z]"),
         caps_freq = map(caps_freq, function(letter) data.frame(table(letter)))) %>%
  unnest()
#                                strings letters Freq
# 1 gctaggggggatggttactactGtgctatggactac       G    1
# 2      gGaagggacggttactaCgTtatggactacT       C    1
# 3      gGaagggacggttactaCgTtatggactacT       G    1
# 4      gGaagggacggttactaCgTtatggactacT       T    2
# 5                  gcGaggggattggcttacG       G    2
```

Comment: What is the difference from @docendo's answer?? I don't see it (other than doing a `paste` at the end) - Same answer imo

Comment: Because this is the requested output. As I quite clearly said, I extended his answer...

Comment: The correct thing to do was to comment under his answer that an additional step can be added to accommodate the pasting part. Re-posting the same answer just to add a line of code sounds a bit like plagiarism. The `tidyverse` addition however, makes it OK as a new answer (Which I also like its output better to be honest)

Answer (score 5):

You can extract all capital letters and then compute the frequencies with table:

```
library(stringr)
lapply(str_extract_all(t, "[A-Z]"), table)
# [[1]]
# 
# G 
# 1 
# 
# [[2]]
# 
# C G T 
# 1 1 2 
# 
# [[3]]
# 
# G 
# 2
```